# Determine the centralizer in $G L_3 (\mathbb{R})$ of each matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine the centralizer in $G L_3 (\mathbb{R})$ of each matrix

a)$A = \begin{bmatrix}  1 &0&0 \\ 0& 2&0\\0&0&3 \end{bmatrix}$.

b)$B = \begin{bmatrix}  0 &1&0 \\ 0& 0&1\\1&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$.

My attempt : i thinks  i take $I_{n\times n}$ matrix  then  both option a) and option b) will be satisfied...

as i don't know  how find the centralizer.
pliz help me

Any hints/solution will be aprreciated

thanks u

Comment: Well, obviously, $I_{3\times 3}$ would be in the centralizer. How about others? Hint: Think about how $A$ and $B$ affect $3\times 3$ matrices

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe..im not able to find can u give me any hints/solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For $A$ consider the diagonal matrices in $GL_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ i.e.

$\{D = (d_{ij}) : d_{ij}= 0 \text{ for } i \neq j \text{ and } d_{11} \cdot d_{22}\cdot d_{33} \neq 0\}$\

and for $B$ consider the set of scalar matrices in $Gl_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ i.e.

$\{ \lambda I_3 : \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}\}$.

Now, by taking elementary matrices (matrices $E_{ij}$ for which $ij$th entry is 1 and rest entries are 0) show that these are precisely the centralizers of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Comment: thanks a lots  @Shubham